# Installing Spark through Ambari

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I've configured cluster of VMs via Ambari.
Now trying to install Spark.

In all tutorials (i.e. [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_spark-guide/content/install-spark-over-ambari.html)) it's pretty simple; Spark installation is similar to other services:

[image: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_spark-guide/content/install-spark-over-ambari.html]

But it appears that in my Ambari instance there is simply no such entry.

How can I add Spark entry to Ambari services?

Comment: What version of HDP are you using?

Comment: @cjackson version is 2.2

Comment: Spark 1.2.1 should be available with HDP2.2. Does the following folder exist on the node running ambari server `/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.2/services/SPARK`?

Comment: @cjackson No. `services` directory contains the following folders: `FALCON, HBASE, HIVE, KNOX, PIG, SQOOP, TEZ, ZOOKEEPER, FLUME, HDFS, KAFKA, OOZIE, SLIDER, STORM, YARN`.

Comment: Unless you plan on using Spark on YARN, you could just install Spark manually. But I agree, it should be part of the HDP 2.2 repo

Answer (score 0):

There should be a SPARK folder under the `/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.2/services` directory. Additionally there should be spark folders identified by their version number under `/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/common-services/SPARK`. Either someone modified your environment or it's a bad and or non-standard install of Ambari.

I would suggest re-installing as it is hard to say exactly what you need to add as its unclear what other things may be missing in the environment.